# IdentityServer4 .net core 2 Authentication Use multiple instances of OpenIDConnect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using IdenitityServer4 Hybrid as shown here -
https://github.com/elanderson/Angular-Core-IdentityServer

Problem - 
I need to add additional project to access . Another .net core 2 web api.

I am trying -

```
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
          {
              options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          })
          .AddCookie()
           .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerAddress"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";

                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("apiApp");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            }).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
          {
              options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerAddress"];
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

              options.ClientId = "abiApp";
              options.ClientSecret = "secret";

              options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
              options.Scope.Clear();
              options.Scope.Add("abiApp");
              options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

              options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
              options.SaveTokens = true;
          });
```

I am getting -

> InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: OpenIdConnect

Without it -

> Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
>   Invalid scope

I need to create two entrances of two different projects . 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assign different names to each configuration. You can also use these names with other parts of the ASP.NET Core auth system such as `ChallengeAsync`.

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect("scheme1", options => {...})
.AddOpenIdConnect("scheme2", options => {...});
```

Comment: there is a default definition of the scheme - 

So , i  just put some names as you suggested - 
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
              {
                  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              })
              .AddCookie()
               .AddOpenIdConnect( "mvc",options =>
                {   })
                .AddOpenIdConnect( "abiApp", options =>
              { });

Comment: There are no schemes like this. Those are the names of the clients. The default schema called OpenIdConnect.

Comment: Still getting - Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
Invalid scope.

Comment: "Unauthorized client" ... are both "mvc" and "abiApp" registered as clients Identity Server? (Is it "abi" or "api"?)